# Change CSSStyleSheet attributes without deleting and inserting

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to modify a css rule written in a file, for example this:

```
.myClass {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom: 0 solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

Now, I want to change only the border-bottom attribute. I found the CSSStylesheet documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet
However, there are only 2 methods: deleteRule and insertRule. Is it possible to only change one attribute in some way? This is my current code on how I modify the CSS file:

```
var customCSSFile = $('link[href="custom-dashboard-theme.css"]')[0].sheet; // get CSS file
var classes = customCSSFile.cssRules;
function getIndex(selectorName) {
    for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {        
        if (classes[x].selectorText == selectorName) {
            return x;
        }         
    }
}

customCSSFile.deleteRule(getIndex(".myClass"));
customCSSFile.insertRule('.myClass {color: #fff;border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)}');
```

However, with CSS rules that have lots of attributes, this seems like a very stupid way. Is there an easier way to just change one attribute?

Comment: just use css variables

Comment: The CSS is generated dynamically. I'm creating a JS solution for some extra modifications

Comment: why not just add a class to the element with a modification for the border? I mean in the css, have a modification from the begining, like this `<div class="block block--success"></div>` place the modification below the myClass and it will override it.

Comment: @Dejan.S the element is created several times from the Shiny framework for R. I'm trying to implement a solution to make easy changes to this. It would be easiest to add the class in the beginning but this is not the purpose.